# Is there any way to "region" dart script via Vscode?

Tags: flutter, dart, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

Is there any way to "region" dart script via Vscode?

Just like C# via visualStudio , the script could be "packed" by "#region" and "#endregion",and canbe folded as well. I try to use "//region" and "//endregion" in dart,it seems that code could not "folded" just as c# via visualstudio does.